# Как правильно поставить пробел между строкой? PHP

Tags: php

Имеется массив:

```
Array ( [0] => ЯБЛОКО ) Array ( [0] => ВИШНЯ )
```

достаю из массива данные:

```
$out = $array[0];
print_r($out);
```

получаю:
**ЯБЛОКОВИШНЯ**

как разделить пробелом эти слова, чтобы получилось:

**ЯБЛОКО ВИШНЯ**

Comment: Не может быть ЯБЛОКОВИШНЯ т.к. в  $array[0] может быть либо яблоко либо вишня

Comment: полный массив: Array ( [0] => ЯБЛОКО ) Array ( [0] => ВИШНЯ [1] => ВИШНЯ )

Comment: но необходим массивы [0], так как имеются и данные с одними словами Array ( [0] => ТОРТ )

Comment: приведи массив в нормальном виде, а не вот это вот ARRAY ().......и покажи реальный код как ты выводишь... это цикл?

Comment: Дополните свой вопрос этим кодом, нажав кнопку "Редактировать" оформив код в соответствии с правилами форматирования.

Comment: так вы в своем коде нигде пробел не выводите. У вас print_r в цикле, сначала он печатает яблоко, на втором проходе цикла он печатает вишня. А где печать пробела ? Или печатайте пробел или собирайте весь вывод сначала в переменную через пробел, а потом выводите

Comment: как места поменять? сейчас ЯБЛОКО ВИШНЯ, хочется чтобы было ВИШНЯ ЯБЛОКО