# Как местами поменять строку в PHP?

Tags: php

Как местами поменять строку?
Сейчас строка выводит ЯБЛОКО ВИШНЯ, хочется чтобы было ВИШНЯ ЯБЛОКО

```
$catname = 'яблоко вишня';
$description = explode(" ", $catname);
    foreach($description as $key){
    $request = file_get_contents('https://htmlweb.ru/json/service/inflect?inflect='.$key.'&grammems=мн,рд');
    $parameters = json_decode($request, true);
    $description = $parameters['items'];
    $arr_unique = array_unique($description);
    $new_description = str_replace($arr_unique[0], "".$arr_unique[0]." ", $arr_unique);
    $out = implode($new_description);
    print_r($out);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. сделать `explode` строки по пробелу
2. сконкатенировать элемент по индексу 1 с элементом по индексу 0

Comment: Ну или сделать ``array_reverse`` и обратно соединить, как вариант

Comment: у меня они оба 0

Comment: array_reverse не помогает

Comment: @JONETON при explode никак не может быть два элемента по индексу 0

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ТС начинал отсюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1370398/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-php Так что еще неизвестно откуда у него эта строка.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский добавил свой код

Comment: @u_mulder добавил код

Comment: @JONETON он совсем отличается от изначального вопроса. догадываться что в $parameters, что в $description и причём тут вся эта куча кода - я не буду. Что нужно сделать с конкретной строкой - я написал

Comment: он выводит ЯБЛОКО ВИШНЯ, необходимо ВИШНЯ ЯБЛОКО, array_reverse не помогает, и присвавивание индекса не подходит так как там могут быть 1 слово, 5 слов и т.д, для каждого присвавивать [0],[1] и т.д не получится, данные динамические

Comment: @JONETON сформулируйте вопрос чётко. сейчас никаких 1 слово 5 слов я не вижу. подумайте как правильно корректно сформулировать вопрос и задайте его. сейчас это что-то непонятно. написано одно, а, по сути, нужно другое